# Objectivity and this site

Tags: discussion

This site, as an education site with educators, is likely to end up soliciting many questions that come down to simple advice. (namely [What language should be first used to introduce coding?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-be-first-used-to-introduce-coding))

How does this site plan to respond to these questions?

**edit**: Here is a link to the example questions: [area51 definition](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460?phase=definition)

Comment: The link to the question is broken. Possibly the Q was deleted? Is it possible to show a locked archive view of the question?

Answer (score 7):

There's a notable difference between a question that can be answered *definitively* with and element of opinion and hard-earned experience, and one that can only be discussed and explored through the debate itself.

See [**Good Subjective, Bad Subjective**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

The question you cited is one of the longest-running, most contentious debates in programming (which language should I learn first). It's not that the question is inherently unfit to be asked — with a lot of back-and-forth, point/counter-point discussion, a reader could conceivably take in all the arguments and make a decision for themselves — but Stack Exchange's one-answer ranking system precludes that type of "leave it open" on-going discussion from occurring by design.

This is a better fit for a threading discussion forum that would actually *allow* these types of debates. It's not really a good fit for *this* site.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, yes, a lot of sites have to allow some subjectivity. However, you want the Q&A to be constructive and you want lists to be manageable. In your example, as Robert Cartaino pointed out, there are a lot of strongly held opinions and few means to limit the number of options.

However, if you ask instead "What factors of a language make it an ideal first language to introduce coding?" that would be more objective and meaningful. It would empower the reader to figure out for themselves which language works best.